# How to evaluate this integral: $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi/8}^{3\pi/8}e^{2x}\sin(2x+\pi/4)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

So I was actually cleaning up my stuff around 15 minutes ago when I found this random piece of paper laying around which contained the integral$$\int_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}e^{2x}\sin\left(2x+\dfrac\pi4\right)dx$$that I might have created around a month (month and a half?) ago, which is a beast of an integral in my opinion. However, I couldn't find any other pieces of paper which contained how to evaluate it, although I thought that I might still be able to evaluate it. Here is my attempt at doing so:$$\int_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}e^{2x}\sin\left(2x+\dfrac\pi4\right)dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}2\int_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}e^{2x}(\sin(2x)+\cos(2x))dx$$Now, what do we do from here? This looked to me like the derivative of $e^{2x}\sin(2x)$, but we don't have a $2$ to spare to get this into$$\dfrac d{dx}f(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)$$form. Or do we? We can obviously do$$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}2\int_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}e^{2x}(\sin(2x)+\cos(2x))dx\implies\dfrac{\sqrt2}4\int_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}2e^{2x}(\sin(2x)+\cos(2x))dx$$can we not? So our integral is now$$\dfrac{\sqrt2}4\int_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}2e^{2x}(\sin(2x)+\cos(2x))dx\implies\dfrac{\sqrt2}4\int_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}\dfrac d{dx}(e^{2x}\sin(2x))dx$$$$\implies\dfrac{\sqrt2}4\left[e^{2x}\sin(2x)\right]_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}\implies\dfrac{\sqrt2}4\left(e^{3\pi/4}\sin(3\pi/4)+\dfrac{\sin(\pi/4)}{e^{\pi/4}}\right)$$$$=\dfrac{\sqrt2e^\pi\sin(3\pi/4)+\sqrt2\sin(\pi/4)}{4e^{\pi/4}}=0.25e^{-0.25\pi}(1+e^\pi)$$$$\approx2.751665550491$$$$\therefore I=\int_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}e^{2x}\sin\left(2x+\dfrac\pi4\right)dx=0.25e^{-0.25\pi}(1+e^\pi)$$

---

### My question

---

Have I evaluated this integral correctly, or what would I do to evaluate it correctly, or does the integral diverge?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B2+x%5D+Sin%5B2+x+%2B+Pi%2F4%5D%2C%7Bx%2C+-Pi%2F8%2C+3+Pi%2F8%7D%5D

Yes, the answer is correct. There's a simpler approach - $e^{2x}\sin(2x) = Im (e^{(2 + 2i)x })$ and $e^{2x}\cos(2x) = Re (e^{(2 + 2i)x })$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic approach is integration by parts, in which $e^{2x}$ is differentiated, so I wouldn't call this much of a "beast", just "intimidating on the face of it."

Note that, with $u=2x+\frac \pi 4$,
$$
\int \sin \left( 2x + \frac \pi 4 \right) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac 1 2 \int \sin \left( u \right) \, \mathrm{d}u
= -\frac 1 2 \cos \left( 2x + \frac \pi 4 \right) + C
$$
and similarly
$$
\int \cos \left( 2x + \frac \pi 4 \right) \, \mathrm{d}x 
=  \frac 1 2 \sin \left( 2x + \frac \pi 4 \right) + C
$$

Organizing our work via the DI method, we get

[image]

Let us have
$$
\mathcal{I} := \int_{-\pi/8}^{3\pi/8} e^{2x} \sin \left( 2 x + \frac \pi 4 \right) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
What the above tells us, then, is that
$$
\mathcal{I}
= - \frac 1 2 e^{2x} \cos \left( 2x + \frac \pi 4 \right) \bigg|_{x=-\pi/8}^{x=3\pi/8}
+ \frac 1 2 e^{2x} \sin \left( 2x + \frac \pi 4 \right) \bigg|_{x=-\pi/8}^{x=3\pi/8}
- \int_{-\pi/8}^{3\pi/8} e^{2x} \sin \left( 2x + \frac \pi 4 \right)
$$
i.e.
$$
\mathcal{I}
= - \frac 1 2 e^{2x} \cos \left( 2x + \frac \pi 4 \right) \bigg|_{x=-\pi/8}^{x=3\pi/8}
+ \frac 1 2 e^{2x} \sin \left( 2x + \frac \pi 4 \right) \bigg|_{x=-\pi/8}^{x=3\pi/8}
- \mathcal{I}
$$
Solve for $\mathcal{I}$.

Answer (score 4):

Your result is correct but a quicker technique is the following.

First reduce to a much more usual integral, by change of variable $t=2x+\frac\pi4:$
$$I:=\int_{-\pi/8}^{+3\pi/8}e^{2x}\sin\left(2x+\dfrac\pi4\right)\,dx=\frac{e^{-\pi/4}}2J,\text{ with }J:=\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt.$$

Next, instead of doing twice an integration by parts, use that $\sin t$ is the imaginary part of $e^{it}$:
$$\begin{align}J&=\operatorname{Im}\left(\int_0^\pi e^{(1+i)t}\,dt\right)\\&=\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{e^{(1+i)\pi}-e^{(1+i)0}}{1+i}\right)\\&=\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{(-e^\pi-1)(1-i)}2\right)\\&=\frac{e^\pi+1}2,
\end{align}$$
and conclude:
$$I=\frac{e^{-\pi/4}(e^\pi+1)}4.$$